# It is necessary to perform the planned action through the apex scheduler

Tags: salesforce, apex

i have this code:

```
public static String currencyConverter() {
        
        allCurrency test = new allCurrency();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        response = http.send(request);
        
        String JSONresponse = response.getBody();
        currencyJSON currencyJSON = (currencyJSON)JSON.deserialize(JSONresponse, currencyJSON.class); 
        test.USD = currencyJSON.rates.USD;
        test.CAD = currencyJSON.rates.CAD;
        test.EUR = currencyJSON.rates.EUR;
        test.GBP = currencyJSON.rates.GBP;

        Log__c logObject = new Log__c();
        logObject.Status_Code__c = String.valueOf(response.getStatusCode());
        logObject.Response_Body__c = response.getBody();
        
        insert logObject;

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            Exchange_Rate__c ExchangeRateObject = new Exchange_Rate__c();
            ExchangeRateObject.CAD__c = currencyJSON.rates.CAD;
            ExchangeRateObject.EUR__c = currencyJSON.rates.EUR;
            ExchangeRateObject.GBP__c = currencyJSON.rates.GBP;
            ExchangeRateObject.USD__c = currencyJSON.rates.USD;
            ExchangeRateObject.Log__c = logObject.id;

            insert ExchangeRateObject;
        }
        return JSON.serialize(test);
    }
```

Here I am getting different currencies and then calling them in LWC and also I create two objects with values.

I want these objects to be created every day at 12PM.

Tell me how to implement this through the apex scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class that `implements Schedulable`. Can be this class, just add that to the header and add `execute` method. Or can be separate class, doesn't matter much.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Something like

```apex
public with sharing MyClass implements Schedulable{
   public static String currencyConverter() { ... your method here }

   public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      currencyConverter(); 
   }
}
```

Once your class saves OK you should be able to schedule it from UI (Setup -> Apex Classes -> button) or with `System.schedule` 1-liner from Developer Console for example.

Alternative would be to have a scheduled Flow - but that's bit more work with making your Apex callable from Flow.

P.S. Don't name your variables `test`. Eventually some time later you may need "real" stuff like `Test.isRunningTest()` and that will be "fun". It's like writing

```
Integer Account = 5; // happy debugging suckers
```